# C++ Preprocessor doesn't process define as expected

Tags: c++, macros, clang, preprocessor

I'm having problems with cpp Preprocessor. I have this Input.h file like this:

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_MOBILE1111
    #define MyTest WEB111
#endif 

int MyTest;
```

I process it with this command (on OSX):

```
cpp -E -P Source/Input.h Generated/Output.h
```

I get this:

```
    #define MyTest WEB111


int MyTest;
```

i.e. **macro MyTest is not getting applied. Why?**

---

After a bunch of experimentation, I found that if I insert an empty line, variable definition, a comment or any other line after #ifndef line - then it works fine.

```
#ifndef PLATFORM_MOBILE1111

    #define MyTest WEB111
#endif 

int MyTest;
```

So the input above gets processed correctly into:

```
int WEB111;
```

Can someone explain to me why that is happening? and how to solve that? Is there an option that I can pass?

---

Edit: I also found that ## (concatenation operator) doesn't work too!

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: Symbols beginning with an underscore and followed by an uppercase letter are reserved for the implementation, so you should rename your macro. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier

Comment: You see, that's why @CodyGray is a diamond, and I'm not ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba I thought your comment was a clever pun on undefined behavior. Perhaps a bit too obtuse if you don't already know why, though.

Comment: It's essentially unanswerable until `_Test` gets renamed to something else, and the problem shown to still persist.

Comment: As others have said, change the name of that macro. But that business with the behavior changing when you add a blank line is **definitely wierd**, and almost certainly **not** the result of using a reserved name.

Comment: I changed the name and I can confirm that the problem persists. I updated my sample code too.

Comment: Perhaps your file has one or more characters that is undisplayed (or undisplayable) by your text editor?

Comment: Look at a hex dump of your source.

Comment: @Bathsheba The standard doesn't define *any* behaviour for a standalone preprocessor.

Comment: You aren't passing `-dD` or similar, so you shouldn't be getting any `#` lines in the output at all. Make sure that's really a `#`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that running preprocessor through `c++` rather than `cpp` solves both of my problems:

```
c++ -E -P Source/Input.h Generated/Output.h
```

BTW.: you need to add `-x c++` flag if you file is not using regular c/c++ extention for `c++` command. `cpp` works fine without that.

Answer (score 4):

Strange! You clearly found a bug in the clang preprocessor!

I can reproduce this as well (`Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)`) on OSX.

This also starts working as expected when you remove the spaces before `#define` (indentation), but leading spaces should not matter at all, and a lot of editors indent `#defines` inside `#ifdefs`.

One hint on what is going on is that in the bogus versions the `#define` is still present in the processed source code, while in the correct version it is not. So apparently the preprocessor did not recognize the `#define` as such at all.

Even this fails (note the leading space):

```
 #define MyTest WEB111
int MyTest;
```

While this works as expected:

```
#define MyTest WEB111
int MyTest;
```

And this results in WEB222:

```
 #define MyTest WEB111
 #define MyTest WEB222
int MyTest;
```

While this results in WEB111:

```
#define MyTest WEB111
 #define MyTest WEB222
int MyTest;
```

Crazy!1!! :-)

It seems that always the first indented `#define` gets ignored.

Now the 'solution': Use:

```
gcc -E Source/Input.cpp -P -o Generated/Output.cpp
```

This works as expected, although it is using the same LLVM.

So I assume the `gcc` executable initializes the preprocessor differently than the `cpp`. This is still a bug in `cpp`.